# CSS translate doesn't get right width in animation in IE 10

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-animations

I have a quirky thing going on. I have a box with a nice little loading indicator. It animates across the full width of the box like this:

```
@keyframes line-moving {
0% {transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);}
40% {transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);}
60% {transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);}
100% {transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);}
}
```

It's nice and clean. You can see it in action here: https://jsfiddle.net/hsmb1f7d/

However, on IE 10, the last part of the animation only goes to about 20% of the width of the box instead of 100%. I can't seem to figure out why. Some more details:

- The animation doesn't get cut off, because it does ease out; so seems like it's a width calculation issue.
- When I remove the animation and just set `transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);` on the element, it **does** get the right width...

Does anyone see why it doesn't get the full width in the animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"It appears IE 10 has some strange bug when transitioning between 2 keyframes with a transform of 0."

The solution is to use almost 0% for two of the keyframes.

Check the full answer here: [translate3d between 0% and negative % in IE10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29607168/translate3d-between-0-and-negative-in-ie10)